# transition animation does not work

Tags: css, transition

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here about transition? Because transition animation does not work at all, neither in chrome nor in opera browser.
Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>ttt</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   body {font: 13px sans-serif; }

#montage-wrap  {width: 820px; height: 200px; }
.montage-block  {width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; display: block; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}

#block1 { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; display: block;
background: url("square.png");

-webkit-transition: top .3s; }

.montage-block:hover #block1  { top: -180px; }

.thumb_content {  }

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="montage-wrao">

<div class="montage-block">
  <span id="block1"></span>
  <div class="thumb_vontent">
        <h1>title</h1>
         <p>subtitle</p>
     </div>
 </div>

</div> <!-- montage wrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to at following css.
I can't see in your css transition for other browsers without webkit.

http://jsfiddle.net/8jQbN/

```
CSS:
-webkit-transition: all 3s ease; /* Firefox */
-moz-transition: all 3s ease; /* WebKit */
-o-transition: all 3s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 3s ease; /* Standard */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add top:0; for #block1 in css since you want to animate "top" element.You can change the value if you want to. The animation will works.

```
body {
font: 13px sans-serif; 
}

#montage-wrap  {
width: 820px; 
height: 200px; 
}
.montage-block  {
width: 200px; 
height: 200px; 
float: left; 
display: block; 
overflow: hidden; 
position: relative;
}

#block1 { 
width: 200px; 
height: 200px; 
position: absolute; 
display: block;
background:red;
top:0;
-webkit-transition: top 1s ease-in-out; 
-moz-transition: top 1s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}

.montage-block:hover #block1  { 
top: -180px; 
}

.thumb_content {  }
```

I'm sorry if this is not the solution for your problem.